# Relation of Adjacency matrices of 2 graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, adjacency-matrix

Let G be the subgraph
of G¯(prime) such that there is an edge between v<sub>i</sub> ∈ V and v<sub>j</sub> ∈ V in G if and only if there is at least one edge between v<sub>i</sub> and v<sub>j</sub> in G¯(prime).

[image: Underlying Graphs]

Any tips or hint to solve about finding A from A¯(prime) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_{ij}$ is equal to 1 if $\bar A_{ij}$ is not equal to zero. This means that there is an edge between $v_i$ and $v_j$ on $G$ if there is at least one edge between them on $\bar G$, as stated in the problem. $A_{ij}$ is zero if $i=j$ or $\bar A_{ij}=0$.

$$A_{ij}=\begin{cases}0 & i=j\textrm{ or }\bar A_{ij}=0\\1 & \bar A_{ij}>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I have solved. Thank you!